# 'npm install' hangs when trying to execute 'npm install express mongoose --save'

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I'm trying to install Node JS packages in command prompt using `npm install express mongoose --save` and it got stuck when installing with the message 'sill audit bulk request' so may I ask any methods to solve the issue?

I expected the installation won't get stuck because I installed node JS and I also tried to uninstall and reinstall but still does not work

Comment: Try doing the steps from this comment https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/2479#issuecomment-851763334

Comment: I executed 'npm config get registry' and when I retry 'npm install express mongoose' it not working everything

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error happened for many reasons, here are several things you can check:

**Check your connection:**

- Make sure your internet can access the website.

**Update npm to the latest version:**

- `npm i -g npm@latest`

**Verify and clear the cache:**

- `npm cache verify`
- `npm cache clean -force`

**Remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`:**

- `rm -rf node_modules`
- `rm package-lock.json`

It worked!

Comment: I am trying to install after I removed ```node_modules``` and ```package-lock.json``` but when executing ```npm install``` still freezes

Comment: I think you have a problem with your internet, you should check VPN or change new connection(you can check by way create a new project and re-install it if it not working so your connection has a problem)